# Multiple conditions for HAVING in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, union, having

I have a query that works, but seems like it could / should be rewritten in a more elegant way. The problem is, I haven't found a way to do this, because of the `HAVING` statement.

I just want to look at which of the 3 stores a customer has shopped in, and assign them a 'main store.'

I ended up `UNION`ing 7 different cases...it's getting a bit ridiculous.

In my perfect world, I'd be able to somehow use `HAVING . .  OR HAVING . .` but this doesn't seem to be in line with the philosophy of MySQL.

```
SELECT Cust_ID, 'Main_store_1' AS Main_Store, sum(StoreName = 'Store_1') as num_Store_1, sum(StoreName = 'Store_2') as num_Store_2, sum(StoreName = 'Store_3') as num_Store_3
FROM shopping_table 
WHERE Cust_ID in (<some list of Cust_IDs>)
AND StoreName in ('Store_1', 'Store_2', 'Store_3')
GROUP BY Cust_ID 
HAVING num_Store_1 > 1 and num_Store_2 = 0 and Store_3 = 0
UNION 
SELECT Cust_ID, 'Main_store_2' AS Main_Store, sum(StoreName = 'Store_1') as num_Store_1, sum(StoreName = 'Store_2') as num_Store_2, sum(StoreName = 'Store_3') as num_Store_3
FROM shopping_table 
WHERE Cust_ID in (<some list of Cust_IDs>)
AND StoreName in ('Store_1', 'Store_2', 'Store_3')
GROUP BY Cust_ID 
HAVING num_Store_1 = 0 and num_Store_2 > 0 and Store_3 = 0
```

and advice / philosophical opining would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you include a sample data set and your expected results? Is a main store a store where a customer has shopped exclusively?

Comment: Yes the main store is a store where the shopper has shopped exclusively (although in real life, there is a case for any combination of stores visited, but the assignment pipes them into one "main store"...hence 7 UNION statements and an overlong chunk of MySQL code)

Comment: Yes as in you are going to provide a schema and sample data so we can *opine* as you say about performance comparisons?

Comment: I don't see how you get to 7 cases of exclusively visiting one store out of three. For a given customer the answer is either store1, store2 or store3, or none. What are the 7 outcomes you see?

Comment: There are other outcomes I didn't bother to put in the question, to keep it brief: If someone shopped at all three stores, then I'd assign them to store1, since it is the flagship store. Similar edge cases for all other combinations.

Comment: But then you could also limit those cases to: if a customer has shopped in store 1 at least once, the main store is that one. Otherwise if customer has shopped in store 2 at least once, the main store is that one. Otherwise if customer has shopped in store 3 at least once, the main store is that. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: It gets ugly, naturally -- if someone shopped in store 1 and 3, but not 2, then store 3 get chosen. If it's store 1 and 2, but not 3, then store 1 gets chosen. ad nauseam, ad nauseam...

Comment: Ok, but with that example there is a clear priority: store 3 is most important, than store 1 and then store 2. Or are you selecting store 2 when the customer was in 2 and 3? In other words, what is the order of priority of the stores? I still think you make it more complex than needed.

Comment: The real life version has 100+ stores and the assignment is a big tangle that I wouldn't want to inflict on any helpful SO compatriot!!

Comment: I would think that there is one store, where if a customer visited it, it would at once be their main store, independent of the other stores they visited. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`...HAVING (num_Store_1 > 1 and num_Store_2 = 0 and Store_3 = 0) OR (num_Store_1 = 0 and num_Store_2 > 0 and Store_3 = 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Without completely re-writing (*I am pretty sure there is an even better way, but it might be rather verbose*), this modification should work:

```
SELECT q.*
, CASE 
  WHEN (num_Store_1 > 1 and num_Store_2 = 0 and Store_3 = 0)
  THEN 'Main_store_1'
  WHEN (num_Store_1 = 0 and num_Store_2 > 0 and Store_3 = 0)
  THEN 'Main_store_2'
  WHEN [more conditions]
  THEN [another string]
  ELSE 'No Main'
  END AS Main_Store
FROM (
  SELECT Cust_ID
    , sum(StoreName = 'Store_1') as num_Store_1
    , sum(StoreName = 'Store_2') as num_Store_2
    , sum(StoreName = 'Store_3') as num_Store_3
  FROM shopping_table 
  WHERE Cust_ID in (<some list of Cust_IDs>)
    AND StoreName in ('Store_1', 'Store_2', 'Store_3')
  GROUP BY Cust_ID 
) AS q
;
```

Comment: Genius. Moving from `HAVING` to the `SELECT` is a great idea.

Comment: You *could* do this without the subquery, but then you'd have a lot of SUM expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It you really are **only** interested in listing customers that shop in one store exclusively, then this could be used:

```
SELECT      Cust_ID, 
            Max(StoreName) as Main_Store, 
            Sum(StoreName = 'Store_1') as num_Store_1,
            Sum(StoreName = 'Store_2') as num_Store_2,
            Sum(StoreName = 'Store_3') as num_Store_3
FROM        shopping_table 
WHERE       Cust_ID in (<some list of Cust_IDs>)
AND         StoreName in ('Store_1', 'Store_2', 'Store_3')
GROUP BY    Cust_ID
HAVING      Count(DISTINCT StoreName) = 1
```

Or if you want to list the other customers as well, and choose as their main store the most important store among those they have visited, then use a `CASE` with a `WHEN` per store, in order of their descending priority:

```
SELECT      Cust_ID, 
            CASE
                WHEN Sum(StoreName = 'Store_1') > 0 THEN 'Store_1'
                WHEN Sum(StoreName = 'Store_2') > 0 THEN 'Store_2'
                WHEN Sum(StoreName = 'Store_3') > 0 THEN 'Store_3'
            END as Main_Store,
            Sum(StoreName = 'Store_1') as num_Store_1,
            Sum(StoreName = 'Store_2') as num_Store_2,
            Sum(StoreName = 'Store_3') as num_Store_3
FROM        shopping_table 
WHERE       Cust_ID in (<some list of Cust_IDs>)
AND         StoreName in ('Store_1', 'Store_2', 'Store_3')
GROUP BY    Cust_ID
```

Comment: In your first example, you won't really need the `SUM` or `MAX` since the `COUNT(DISTINCT StoreName) = 1` eliminates the need. In the second, everyone who has visited store 1 even a single time will appear to have it as their main store, even if they've visited store3 a thousand times.

Comment: According to `SQL` standards you need to aggregate the selected fields you don't group by, so the `SUM` and `MAX` are needed. And you are right about the second observation. It is intended like that. The OP has not indicated the difference in count level should be taken into consideration with a weighting  of some sort.